# App Store version Update issues

Tags: ios, app-store, updates

Team,

We have released new App Version (iOS) and it is Live, I have downloaded the App and the same version is showing again in "Updates", I have updated the App multiple times but the Same repeats. What may be the cause.

Can any one help.

The Version it is showing as same what we have given (Current Version). But inside the App we are showing the build version and build details they are showing the Old version details.

Is there any issue from Apple

Comment: Do you alter the info.plist programatically?

Comment: Not altering, we are just getting the data and displaying in our Info screen

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the problem is, but this other guy had the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253965/app-is-always-showing-update-option-even-i-update-download-app.
I just changed the description of the version, e.g.: "Bug fixes" to "Bug fixes." and saved. It's working fine now.

Comment: We have reported the issue to Apple, Seems the issue is at there end.